# logic from SCJP book related to Collections

Tags: java, scjp

```
public class Person {

    private String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return 420;
    }
}
```

Based on the above program the answer is:

Answer: The time to find the value from HashMap with a Person key depends on the size of the map.

I have no clue/idea how come the answer is as above. I thought it was wrong hashcode() method implementation but the only options are as follows:

- Which statement is true?
- A. The time to find the value from HashMap with a Person key depends
  on the size of the map.
- B. Deleting a Person key from a HashMap will delete all map entries
  for all keys of type Person.
- C. Inserting a second Person object into a HashSet will cause the
  first Person object to be removed as a duplicate.
- D. The time to determine whether a Person object is contained in a
  HashSet is constant and does NOT depend on the size of the map.

Answer: A

If anybody can provide some understanding on the same will be great as I won't be able to find any answers on the net for this

Comment: Since every instance of Person will have the same value for hashCode (which is valid, just not recommended), you can't search based on the hashCode. So, it 'll have to check all the instances one by one.

Comment: So it will have to go through all the values in haspmap to find the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HashMap uses hashcode to place the entries in the bucket and equals to locate them.
If all entries have the same hashcode then they will all end up in the same bucket. Now whenever you will request something from the map , the hashmap will go through all the entries from the same bucket and call equals on each entry to find the one requested by you. That's why

> The time to find the value from HashMap with a Person key depends on
>   the size of the map.

is correct answer

Comment: Got more clarity now, but after going through all the entries, how do we know which entry will be picked? as the hashcode() returns 420 for all of them.

Comment: Hashcode in only used to find the bucket, but `equals` is use to locate the entry . For e.g. Let say your map contains `person1,person2,....` . If you call map.get(person1) , hashmap will first find the bucket(using hashcode) and will then use equals to return the correct entry

Answer (score 0):

To find an item in a HashMap normally, the hash code is used to find which "bucket" the item was placed in. Because of the possibility of hash collisions (that is, two items that hash to the same value), the items are then compared using `.equals()`.

In this case, all of the items have a hash collision (as all of them have a hash of 420).

This means that it will need to do a `.equals()` check on every item in the map as they're all in the same bucket, meaning that to find the item will take an amount of work proportional to the number of items in the map.

Comment: Good one!. So it shifts automatically to use .equals() method only when there are hashcode collisions?

Comment: It always confirms with .equals() once it's located the items using the hash, just in case the hashCode collision is on the item being searched for and the one item in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a wrong hashcode, its a poor hash function.  Whatever is the object, its trying to generate the same hash key.

As we have the same hash code getting generated, collision occurs. One of the collision resolution technique is chaining.  So what ever objects added to the map would get chained in a single bucket.  So we need to traverse through the chain to get the right object hence the answer